# How to input English-Character in non-English keyboard

Tags: autohotkey

I'm a Chinese guy.This question trapped me very long time.This is my current method to input English-Charater `()`in my Chinese-input-method:

```
^b::
    ClipSaved := ClipboardAll
    Clipboard=()
    Send ^v
    Clipboard := ClipSaved
Return
```

But,I really don't want to call the clipboard to do this thing,and the *clipboard method* is inconvenient to input *multi-line text*.Any better suggestion can give?

---

**Note it is () but not （）**

Comment: sorry, I don't understand the problem. why not `send ()`?

Comment: @Blauhirn If you `send ()` directly in non-English keyboard.The `()` will be `（）`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about sending the [ASCII values](http://www.asciitable.com/) for left/right parentheses?

```
F3::
SendInput, {ASC 40}{ASC 41}
return
```

**Output:**

```
()
```

***Edit for the comments:***

Say we want to use other ASCII characters, such as curly braces: {}

Their decimal representations are 123 and 125 respectively.

So

```
F3::
SendInput, {ASC 123}{ASC 125}
return
```

Gets you:

```
{}
```

Comment: I really want to kiss you deeply...You don't know. This problem haunt me very long time(almost one year)..Thanks very very much..

Comment: In your code. I want to input many character I should use so many `{}`?

Comment: @yode Glad it works for you. :) If you want to put in other characters that are also affected by the Chinese keyboard, simply replace the ASCII value in the above code with what's desired. http://www.asciitable.com/ is a good resource for this, and you just need to replace the numbers with the Decimal (Dec) for the character(s) desired. I'll update the code with an example for the curly braces so you see what I mean.

Comment: `SendInput, {ASC 40}{ASC 41}` sometime give me [such output](http://i.stack.imgur.com/RhWZL.png),Could you help to test what you have get after your run `SendInput, {ASC 40}{ASC,109}{ASC,97}{ASC,112}{ASC,108}{ASC,101}{ASC 41}`?

Comment: And don't worry I have [more advanced method](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LNtJr.png) to get that sequence..

Comment: @yode Ah, I see what you mean. Unless many of the ASCII characters are being altered by your keyboard, you should be able to just input the normal symbols inside curly braces instead of using the ASCII codes. `SendInput, {ASC 40}{ASC 41}{$}{%}{#}` etc.

Comment: @yode I would guess the squares (usually referred to as tofu boxes) are font issues inside what appears to be a notebook you're using for your coding. The box is usually a fallback character for when problems arise. If you can change the font, I recommend Google's Noto font: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noto_fonts as it was primarily built to address this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153990/discussion-between-yode-and-david-metcalfe).

Comment: Are you [there](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/39062248#39062248)? :)