# How to input somes chacters by Chr()

Tags: autohotkey

I'm newbie in *AutoHotKey*, I try to use *SendInput* to input 3 Characters by `Chr` like this

```
^Numpad1::
    SendInput %Chr(44) %Chr(8451) %Chr(12290)
Return
```

I don't know how to implement it and I don't want to use three `SendInput` to do this, I mean whether the `Chr` and the `SendInput` can be a same line. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you need to stick with `Chr()`? Don't you want to simply use those characters directly? Just asking. Using them directly seems much more practical to me. I keep AHK file in utf-8 format, so there is no problem with literals. In your case: `SendInput D℃。`

Comment: @miroxlav Yes,I stick with `Chr()`,because I'm in Chinese keyboard,I hard to input English character correctly sometimes,but [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43331263/why-my-stringreplace-dont-work) give me hope to solve this question.Help,please.I suffer this very long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [expression mode](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm):

```
^Numpad1::
    SendInput % Chr(44) Chr(8451) Chr(12290)
Return
```

`%` followed by a `space` causes the parameters to be evaluated as an expression

Comment: Good solution.It's seem more concise.And further more,the *Autohotkey* have function *map* function like *Python*?I mean sometimes I have to 20 chacters,so I have to use 20 `Chr`?Of course,I already have their ASCII

Comment: Put codes in an [array](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Arrays.htm) (e.g., `A:=[1,2,3,4]`), and then build a string by iterating over it `for c in A { s .= chr(c) }`

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I found a way how to do it on single line, without variable or `Return`:

```
^Numpad1::SendInput % Chr(44)Chr(8451)Chr(12290)
```

Remember, you can still avoid most codes and immediately see meaning of your definitions. Use **Character Map** application to get the characters directly, then put them into the file. Numbers rarely have a benefit over directly written symbols. Just `,` (comma) needs escaping to `{,}`:

```
`Numpad1::SendInput {,}℃。
```

Comment: I have to say,you save me almost..I can solve [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42533851/how-to-input-english-character-in-non-english-keyboard) now.

Comment: And further more,the *Autohotkey* have function *map* function like *Python*?I mean sometimes I have to 20 chacters,so I have to use 20 `Chr`?Of course,I already have their ASCII

Comment: Fun,I'd like the new version more.Thanks for help,maybe I should give some opening time then accept the answer.

Comment: Yes,the new method **cannnot** expand English Character in Chinese-keyboard,So I'd like the `Chr` more.And I can get any ASCII about andy character easily.